# Simple comments output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller I have:

```
def show
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @entry.comments
end
```

Now in the view:

```
<% if !@comments.empty? %>
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I know `@comments` is not empty, but here I get `@comments.empty? == true`
When I add `<%= @comments %>` before `if` statement, all works fine. `empty?` is `false`, and I get comment ids. It looks like query to get comments is run when I add this new line? Any idea why and how can I make it work without this additional line?

Comment: Can you please rephrase? I don't get it.

Comment: Basically, when you add <%= \@comments %> before the <% if !\@comments.empty? %> line the \@comment array is not empty, and has correct comment records. Without this line \@comment array is empty. Ps. had to escape \@, as stackoverflow treats it like the name mention.

Comment: it works when instead if !@comments.empty? I use !@comments.all.empty?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need this statement at all?

This will work

```
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.id %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, tested it and you're right it works. Any idea why "if version" haven't?

Comment: it can be AREL lazy loading, but i thought it should fetch records on `empty?` call too.

Answer (score 1):

Never use `if !`. Instead use `unless`.

Here you don't even need a empty check statement at all. `.each` iterate only when there is some values.